# Having same property name in abstract class and its child class scenario

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I have an `Abstract` class:

```
public abstract class ClassParent{
    protected Integer id;
    protected String message;
}
```

and a its child class:

```
public class ClassChild extends ClassParent{
    private Integer id;
    private String message;
}
```

what will happen in this scenario? is it going to inherit its base class properties or will give an error on runtime? where should be the getters and setters for these properties?

Comment: sounds easy enough to try doesn't it?

Comment: It is not giving me an error, that's why I am curious.

Comment: The parent's value gets hidden

Comment: Why does the error not answer your question?

Comment: But why it is allowing me to write these properties again in child class? should not be obvious that these will be inherited from parent?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass property hides the parent class property. This called shadowing and allowed in java. it is best to avoid it. You can verify this with following code sample

```
public class ClassChild extends ClassParent {
    private Integer id;
    private String message;

    ClassChild(Integer id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassChild{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassChild cs = new ClassChild(1, "Test");

        System.out.println(cs);
        System.out.println(cs.message);
        System.out.println(cs.id);
        System.out.println(((ClassParent)cs).id);
        System.out.println(((ClassParent)cs).message);

    }
}
```